# header() error not shown in php

Tags: php, header, error-reporting

I wrote a PHP program,
I use `session_start()` and `header()` functions, I know I should use this functions before I sending anything to client. it's ok, but for test I send a test message to client with `echo "test";` before using header(), but I didn't get any error and header function work without any problem !

In previous versions of PHP at this time I will got a message like :

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /some/file.php:22) in /some/file.php on line 60
```

I wan't to know why I didn't get any error message ?!

My php version is 5.3.1 and `error_reporting` is on `E_ALL`

Comment: @LinusKleen Yes, As I said `header()` will work, `session_start()` will work too. I use header for redirect to a page `header("Location: mypage.php");`

Comment: are the file.php UTF-8 encode?

Comment: @MahdiParsa Yes, encoding is UTF-8

Comment: @MahdiParsa without BOM, but this is not my question, my question is why I didn't get any error, I should receive an error when I send a parameter to client before using `header()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem,
I don't use any FrameWork.

the problem was `error_reporting('E_ALL');`

I wrote this code on first of my program, and so PHP didn't return any errors !
I deleted this line and I get the errors !

This is kidding because this line said to PHP to show ALL errors !
I don't know why PHP don't show any errors.

Answer (score 1):

You don't see the error because
a. output buffering is on
b. the server ignores your error_reporting function because something else instructs it otherwise
run `phpinfo();` and see what it says there about `output buffering` and about `error_reporting`.

Comment: thanks for your response, output_buffering >> no value and
output_handler>>no value and error_reporting >> 30719

Comment: `php.ini` settings do not supercede settings of `error_reporting()`

Comment: @LinusKleen Those of `.htaccess` does or when working with IIS sapi - it does.

@MajAfy do you see other errors ? like notices for undefined variables ?

Comment: @LinusKleen in `php.ini` the `error_reporting` is `E_ALL` : `error_reporting = E_ALL`

Comment: @Alex Yes, another errors (Warning, Fatal, Notice and ...) will show

Comment: Than, apparently, there is no error in your code ;) Could you put your code on pastebin so we could examine it? + I suggest you try a simple, faulty case, such as 

 <?php
 echo 'hi';
 header('Location: google.com')

Answer (score 0):

This might be possible because you write into an output buffer (ob_start) which doesn't actually return anything to the client until you explicitly flush the buffer (ob_flush or ob_end_*) or the script ends.

The fact that you can't send headers after you begun writing the body part of your HTTP response is not a php but a HTTP protocol limitation, so this cannot be version specific either.

Many frameworks like the Zend Framework use output buffers so a developer doesn't need to care about the order.