# I can't see some PHP errors

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [header() error not shown in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508426/header-error-not-shown-in-php)

My `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` file has the next configuration:

```
display_errors = On
log_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

and I can view errors like `Undenifed variable`, `Parse error` and so on in the browser, but with the next code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
   header('hola: adios');
?>
```

I can't see the `Headers already sent` error. Also with the Developer tools of Chrome I can see that the header `hola: adios` is set. 
How could I see those type of errors? 
Thanks.

Comment: You have automatic output buffering on, hence, there is no error....

Comment: @Wrikken I have set `output_buffering = Off` in my php.ini and restarted apache but no difference.

Comment: Well, in that case, what does phpinfo() at that exact point say about output buffers, error reporting levels, display error settings, et al. ?

Comment: @Wrikken sorry, apache was not restarted. Now I can see the error. But this make me wonder: if we can set output_buffering = Off then why bother about PHP closing tag? Thanks.

Comment: See [Headers already sent "Outbut buffering workaround"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php#~workaround) and why it is amateurish.

Comment: Those 2 have... not much to do with one another? How do you mean? (and about the last ending `?>` in a file, Zend actually believes we shouldn't put it there, and yes, you can omit the last `?>` in a file)

Comment: @Wrikken I mean that if we can set the output buffering off then omit the last `?>` is not necessary. But I have seen that the output buffering is just a workaround (in the link that @mario sent).

Comment: .. I still do not see the connection....? Omitting the last `?>`is not necessary with or without ob buffering... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not showing you an error because it is NOT!
the function is

```
header(string,replace,http_response_code)
```

where string may be anything you wanna set as a header field:value. There isn't a list what can be used or what not. You can always have custom header fields.

check the manual - http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php.

```
<?php
header('inappropriate stuff');
?>
```

try this and you wont be getting anything in header packet since php can't find a colon ':' as a separator inside the string which separates the header field from the value.

NOTE: If you plan to use it with session, **session_start()** must be the first function to run at the beginning of your execution.

Comment: You are missing the point, it is not about the kind of header, but the fact that html has been outputted before the call to `header`.

Comment: -1, watch your language.

Comment: may be I didnt get the point he was trying to reflect through the question. But then it makes me wonder why its not showing an error. and yes. output buffering..

Comment: Oh!! sorry about that. I was just going to edit that and you did @Charles. Sorry for that.